# querydsl, set null values to column causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, null, querydsl

First time I post on stackoverflow, but I really need some help on this.

I don't use class generation for mapping my entities. I'm using queryDSL version 4.0.5

Here is my code :

```
    SQLTemplates templates = MySQLTemplates.builder().printSchema().build();
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration( templates );

    try
    {
        Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );

        final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "" );

        SQLQuery sqlQuery = new SQLQuery( connection, configuration );

        // querying
        NumberPath< Long > volume = Expressions.numberPath( Long.class, "volume" );

        RelationalPathBase< Object > r = new RelationalPathBase< Object >( Object.class, "", "test", "mstf" );

        Provider< java.sql.Connection > provinv = new Provider< Connection >()
        {

            @Override
            public Connection get()
            {
                return connection;
            }
        };

        SQLQueryFactory queryFactory = new SQLQueryFactory( configuration, provinv );

        queryFactory.update( r ).setNull( volume ).execute();

    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When executing, I got a wonderful NullPointerException because of this code in class ColumnMetadata:

```
public int getJdbcType() {
    return jdbcType;
}
```

Of course we have a jdbcType of type INTEGER, it is null and we must return an int...

Any idea how I can put null data in my column ?
Many thanks !!